# Bool field as a unique index

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

Can a Bool field become a unique index and used for a foreign key relationship in conjunction with another table's index?

I don't think it can become primary key but what about unique index? Every time I try to make it into a unique index it converts it into a tinyint.

**EDIT**

So I have a SQL relationship problem. Lets say I have a database where I want to keep records of information about individuals. Now I have setup a table to take on that information. Okay so far so good.

Often times duplicate information can be discovered in the table and it would be removed. A record is considered a duplicate if a particular field has the same value as another field in another row. Example: Duplicate emails.

Now I want to create another table in the database to keep track of every duplicate that is ever discovered and deleted. My first thought into this was to create a Foreign Key relationship. So I created and then connected a dupes table to my persons table. The relationship was a simple Foreign to Primary key relationship with an on delete constraint.

Now while that may have worked at first the problem arose that the dupes table was receiving records that were deleted even if they were not deleted because they were dupes. This was a problem because even if I decided to delete a person from the persons table just because I did not like them, they would stored in the dupes table anyway.

Then I thought, why not create a disposition field in the persons table and connect that as a unique or primary key to my dupes table's index foreign key. Well the problem is a unique key must have a unique value so multiple dispositions of dupe or I don't like you would not work. The other option was to make the disposition field a primary key. That has the same problem though.

What would be the right relationship for this problem?

Comment: Part of an unique index, or an unique index ? A unique index bool will let you have 2 rows in a table. (3 if it accepts nulls)

Comment: As a unique index. Is there anyway to funnel rows into another table when they are deleted AND also have a false value in field foo?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, still don't see what you're tyring to achieve. What has deletion of rows to do with this? A [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) can constrain deletion, but how would that move (if that is what you mean by “funnel”) any data to another table? Please clarify.

Comment: by adding a on delete, cascade constraint it will make a deleted row on one table transfer to another table that it has a relationship with via foreign key.

Comment: This seems not correct neither in mssql nor in mysql foreign key constraints with cascade will cascade the delete command to the foreign key table - they won't copy data. (Point me to the mysql reference page explaining something else, if i'm wrong).
What you need is an on delete trigger i think - there you can do anything you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially a bool-value in sql (or bit in mssql) is an very short integer. So basically there's no reason that it would not be allowed as foreign key.
But from a design perspective it does not make any sense.

Comment: Well the reason I want to make it a unique index is so that I can add a on delete constraint to another table so I can funnel in every row that has a `false` value into another table when that row is deleted. 

Makes sense?

Comment: No this does not make sense, since you can delete as follows
DELETE FROM <Table> WHERE <Field> = 0

Comment: I have to do that manualy. I am trying to setup a entity relationship so it does it automatically with the help of constraints. On delete for example. I can write any number of queries to achieve my result but the trick is in making it a relationship.

Comment: But you have to mark them with false, which makes you send an UPDATE <Table> SET <Field> = 0 WHERE <someConstraint> and then an DELETE FROM <BoolTable> WHERE <bool> = 0 and then an INSTER INTO <BoolTable> VALUES (0).
So which one is more straight foreward?

Comment: well were still on the first problem. The objective here is to create an entity relationship that would connect the index of table `B` to the Unique Index (or primary key) of table `A`. I want the unique index to be a bool value. Why? So all values that are true for example, can be transferred to table `B` thanks to a `on delete` constraint. The constraint does the work load. No queries should be involved what so ever, the point of this is just as an entity model.

Comment: I can understand where this is getting confusing. Let me make an edit to my original post with some more details.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, BOOL field can be a primary or unique key. In case of unique key it is possible to set NULL as value.

About the TINYINT: MySQL does not support BOOL data type, it uses TINYINT instead.

From the reference - *BOOL, BOOLEAN: These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1).*